# Binary OR not working in Symfony Propel Criteria

Tags: sql, symfony-1.4, propel

I am using Symfony 1.4 and Propel(ORM), i want to execute SQL query (`SELECT * FROM 'myblog'
WHERE 'blog_title' LIKE '%symfony%'
OR 'blog_post' LIKE '%symfony%'`)
want to get all the records from myblog which contains the word symfony.
I wrote the Symfony code as,

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(MyblogPeer::BLOG_TITLE, "%symfony%", Criteria::LIKE);
$c->addOr(MyblogPeer::BLOG_POST, "%symfony%", Criteria::LIKE);
$my_blog = MyblogPeer::doSelect($c);
```

but it returns a empty set. Is there any thing wrong in giving the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that in order to create an OR in the where closure, you need to create a Criterion and then add that criterion to the query, it should be something like this:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$criterion = $c->getNewCriterion(MyblogPeer::BLOG_TITLE, "%symfony%", Criteria::LIKE);
$criterion->addOr($c->getNewCriterion(MyblogPeer::BLOG_POST, "%symfony%", Criteria::LIKE));
$c->add($criterion);
$my_blog = MyblogPeer::doSelect($c);
```